# Ubuntu 20.04 Stuck at /dev/sda5 clean ... files blocks after motherboard change

Tags: boot, grub2, fsck

I upgraded from i5 6500 to i3 12100 and changed mobo and ram also. Currently i have only one drive in it.

Previously i was stuck at the gnu grub menu and i had to run: set prefix=, set root=, insmod normal, normal so i could get past that. After that i could boot into ubuntu recovery mode in which i run smart test for drive and its fine.

Then i ran these: sudo update-grub, sudo grub-install /dev/sda and rebooted. It will reboot fine to the grub menu and i choose ubuntu in it but gets stuck and says something like recovering journal, /dev/sda5 clean files blocks...

I reboot and go change sudo /etc/fstab and change the last number from 1 to 0 so it would not run fsck as that was recommended somewhere and tried that but it still gets stuck in the same screen.

E: I do not have gpu in it nor have i installed anything from nvidia.
Any advice?

Comment: If 20.04, you may need newer version of Ubuntu to have updated kernel & drivers. Have you tried booting live installer with 22.04 or 23.10 to see if they work?

Comment: Upgraded 20.04 to 22.04 and ugpraded kernel now it works